Элементы пагинации в Slider Swiper
Пытаюсь реализовать Slider Swiper типа (Pagination custom)

Но чтобы именно элементы пагинации дополнительно с кнопками Next/Prev были такого типа как на рисунке

Помогите каким образом их можно реализовать

Правильно застилить элементы. Без вашего кода и стилей, вопрос не имеет смысла

Вот это ваш вариант, играйтесь: https://codepen.io/takaneichinose/pen/KKbNpgJ

обратитесь через css к селекторам этих компонентов и настройте как вам удобно
